# Finding Documents on CouchDB 3.1 with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, json, couchdb

I need to query our couchdb tennant database using PowerShell.  I've put together the following after trawling through different forums, help documents etc.

```
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString 'MyPassword' -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ('MyUsername', $password)
 

 $Params = @{
     Method = "POST"
     Uri = "MyURL/tenantdb-ffffffff-0000-0000-0006-000000000000/_find"
     ContentType = "application/json"
     Body = '{"selector": {"type":{"$eq":"referenceRequest"}},"processedDateTime":["$gt": "2023-01-26"]}'
     
 }
 Invoke-WebRequest @Params -Credential $credential
```

I get the following error...

```
Invoke-WebRequest : {"error":"bad_request","reason":"invalid UTF-8 JSON"}
```

Could anyone help/advise please?

I apologise in advance, this is new to me.

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, you simply used incorrect JSON.

This part is wrong:

```
"processedDateTime":["$gt": "2023-01-26"]
```

You're passing an array which doesn't use the property syntax with a `:`. That also needs to be an object wrapped with `{}` rather than `[]`:

```
"processedDateTime":{"$gt": "2023-01-26"}
```

The positioning of your curly brackets is also looking wrong. I'm pretty sure it should be

```
{"selector": {"type":{"$eq":"referenceRequest"},"processedDateTime":{"$gt": "2023-01-26"}}}
```

so that the field is inside the `selector` object.